# How to implement the relationship for any two representatives located in different parts of the database?

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

**Task:** Create a database query that gives a hierarchical relationship for any two representatives of the genus, in other words, find out who is the ancestor and who is the descendant.
**Database:**

```
parent('Rurik', 'Igor').
parent('Igor', 'Olga').
parent('Olga', 'Svyatoslav Igorevich').
parent('Svyatoslav Igorevich', 'Yaropolk').
parent('Yaropolk', 'Svyatopolk Okoyanny').
parent('Svyatoslav Igorevich', 'Vladimir Svyatoy').
parent('Vladimir Svyatoy', 'Yaroslav I Mudry').
parent('Yaroslav I Mudry', 'Svyatoslav').
parent('Svyatoslav', 'Oleg').
parent('Oleg', 'Vsevolod II').
parent('Yaroslav I Mudry', 'Izyaslav I').
parent('Izyaslav I', 'Svyatopolk').
parent('Yaroslav I Mudry', 'Vsevolod I').
parent('Vsevolod I', 'Vladimir Monomah').
parent('Vladimir Monomah', 'Mstislav Veliky').
parent('Mstislav Veliky', 'Izyaslav II').
parent('Vladimir Monomah', 'Yaropolk II').
parent('Vladimir Monomah', 'Yuriy Dolgoruky').
parent('Yuriy Dolgoruky', 'Mikhail I').
parent('Yuriy Dolgoruky', 'Vsevolod Bolshoe Gnezdo').
parent('Vsevolod Bolshoe Gnezdo', 'Yuriy II').
parent('Vsevolod Bolshoe Gnezdo', 'Yaroslav II').
parent('Vsevolod Bolshoe Gnezdo', 'Konstantin I').
parent('Yaroslav II', 'Andrey').
parent('Andrey', 'Vasiliy').
parent('Vasiliy', 'Konstantin II').
parent('Konstantin II', 'Dmitriy Suzdalskiy').
parent('Yaroslav II', 'Vasiliy Kostramskoy').
parent('Yaroslav II', 'Yaroslav III Tverskoy').
parent('Yaroslav III Tverskoy', 'Mikhail II Svyatoy').
parent('Mikhail II Svyatoy', 'Alexandr II').
parent('Yaroslav II', 'Alexandr Nevskiy').
parent('Alexandr Nevskiy', 'Andrey Gorodeckiy').
parent('Alexandr Nevskiy', 'Dmitriy Pereyaslavskiy').
parent('Alexandr Nevskiy', 'Daniil Moskovskiy').
parent('Daniil Moskovskiy', 'Yuriy III Moskovskiy').
parent('Daniil Moskovskiy', 'Ioan I Kalita').
parent('Ioan I Kalita', 'Simeon Gordiy').
parent('Ioan I Kalita', 'Ioan II Krotkiy').
parent('Ioan II Krotkiy', 'Dmitriy Donskoy').
parent('Dmitriy Donskoy', 'Vasiliy I').
parent('Vasiliy I', 'Vasiliy II Temniy').
parent('Vasiliy II Temniy', 'Ioan III').
parent('Ioan III', 'Vasiliy III').
parent('Vasiliy III', 'Ioan IV').
parent('Ioan IV', 'Fedor').

relations(X,Z) :- parent(X,Z).
relations(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y), ancestor(Y,Z).
```

**Example:**

```
?- relations('Rurik', 'Oleg').
```

Rurik - ancestor, Oleg - descendant.
**How to implement this?**

Comment: What rules have you written this far to attempt this?

Comment: I added a couple of lines to the database, but this is not what I need, because when I request: 
?- relations ('Rurik', 'Oleg') it will print: true, 
but I need: 
?- relations('Rurik', 'Oleg') ---> Rurik - ancestor, Oleg - descendant.

Comment: seems like You need a ``ancestor(Ancestor,Descendent) :- _etc_`` and a ``descendent(Descendent,Ancestor) :- _etc_`` to be able to answer those questions .

Comment: may be, but how to implement this?